# optimize pyspark code to find a keyword and its count in a dataframe

Tags: optimization, pyspark, databricks

We have a lot of files in our s3 bucket. The current pyspark code I have reads each file, takes one column from that file and looks for the keyword and returns a dataframe with count of keyword in the column and the file.
Here is the code in pyspark. (we are using databricks to write code if that helps)

```
import s3fs
fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem()
from pyspark.sql.functions import lower, col
keywords = ['%keyword1%','%keyword2%']
prefix = ''
deployment_id = ''
pull_id = ''
paths = fs.ls(prefix+'/'+deployment_id+'/'+pull_id)
result = []
errors = []
try:
    for path in paths:
        df = spark.read.parquet('s3://'+path)
        print(path)
        for keyword in keywords:
            for col in df.columns:
                filtered_df = df.filter(lower(df[col]).like(keyword))
                filtered_count = filtered_df.count()
                if filtered_count > 0 :
                    #print(col +' has '+ str(filtered_count) +' appearences')
                    result.append({'keyword': keyword, 'column': col, 'count': filtered_count,'table':path.split('/')[-1]})
        

except Exception as e:
    errors.append({'error_msg':e})
    

try:
    errors = spark.createDataFrame(errors)
except Exception as e:
    print('no errors')
try:
    result = spark.createDataFrame(result)
    result.display()
except Exception as e:
    print('problem with results. May be no results')
```

I am new to pyspark,databricks and spark. Code here works very slow. I know that cause we have a local code in python that is faster than this one. we wanted to use pyspark, databricks cause we thought it would be faster and on local code we need to put aws access keys every day and some times if the file is huge it gives a memory error.
NOTE - The above code reads data faster but the search functionality seems to be slower when compared to local python code
here is the python code in our local system

```
def search_df(self,keyword,df,regex=False):
        start=time.time()
        
        if regex:
            mask = df.applymap(lambda x: re.search(keyword,x) is not None if isinstance(x,str) else False).to_numpy()
        else:
            mask = df.applymap(lambda x: keyword.lower() in x.lower() if isinstance(x,str) else False).to_numpy()
```

I was hoping if I could have any code changes to the pyspark so its faster.
Thanks.

tried changing
.like(keyword) to .contains(keyword) to see if thats faster. but doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Check out the below code. Have defined a function that uses List Comprehensions to search each column in the df for a keyword. Next calling that function for each keyword. There will be a new df returned  for each keyword, which then need to be unioned using reduce function.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from functools import reduce

sampleData = [["Hello s1","Y","Hi s1"],["What is your name?","What is s1","what is s2?"] ]
df = spark.createDataFrame(sampleData,["col1","col2","col3"])
df.show()

# Sample input dataframe
+------------------+----------+-----------+
|              col1|      col2|       col3|
+------------------+----------+-----------+
|          Hello s1|         Y|      Hi s1|
|What is your name?|What is s1|what is s2?|
+------------------+----------+-----------+

keywords=["s1","s2"]

def calc(k) -> DataFrame:
  return df.select([F.count(F.when(F.col(c).rlike(k),c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns] ).withColumn("keyword",F.lit(k))

lst=[calc(k) for k in keywords]

fDf=reduce(DataFrame.unionByName, [y for y in lst])

stExpr="stack(3,'col1',col1,'col2',col2,'col3',col3) as (ColName,Count)"
fDf.select("keyword",F.expr(stExpr)).show()

# Output
+-------+-------+-----+
|keyword|ColName|Count|
+-------+-------+-----+
|     s1|   col1|    1|
|     s1|   col2|    1|
|     s1|   col3|    1|
|     s2|   col1|    0|
|     s2|   col2|    0|
|     s2|   col3|    1|
+-------+-------+-----+
```

You can add a where clause at the end to filter rows greater than 0 ==>

`where("Count >0")`

Comment: thank you very much for this. is possible to have counts which are greater than 0 and the column name
like this 
column    count
id.            15
name.      30

Comment: @MayureshDeodhar  I have modified the code, can u check if that's the format u require.  Basically unpivoted the previous output to arrive at the expected one.